# Deleted updates still appear in WSUS console

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus

I have set up a WSUS server and set it to download updates from microsoft.com. Later I decided I don't need all the updates I have previously selected and since I couldn't find a "delete" button I deleted the entire folder, where I was locally storing them. But even after restarting and changing the local storage directory (with the "-skipcopy" argument) all the updates are still present in the WSUS management console. How can I remove them from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, and most importantly: Don't ever modify any WSUS files/folders/databases by hand. Everything you need to do can and should be done from either the administration console or `wsusutil`.**

To answer your question, WSUS uses a database (WID by default) to store information about downloaded updates, computer status, configuration, etc. Deleting the update files from the disk doesn't remove them from the database.

By deleting the updates from the disk, you've left WSUS in an inconsistent state; the database lists the updates as downloaded and available, but the files are missing. I've never done this, but I would assume this is going to cause you trouble down the line. If I was you, I would do a `wsusutil reset` and start over.

---

Moving forward, you should look at the `Download update files to this server only when updates are approved` option. This ensures that only updates you approve are actually downloaded. If an approved & downloaded update is later declined or no longer needed by any computers, the `Server Cleanup Wizard` (which you should absolutely run on a regular basis) will automatically remove the associated files.

[image: WSUS Update Files and Languages]